# Interactive Shell for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, console, pdb

When working on a web app in python/flask, I am able to `import pdb` at the top of a file, and then call `pdb.set_trace()` somewhere in my code to "pause" the web app and open an interactive console in my terminal for debugging.  I am looking for something similar in Ruby/Rails.  What exists for this purpose, and how do I use it?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails

Comment: https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.

The gem `debugger` is created for this purpose.  To start, run

```
gem install debugger
```

After, add the line `debugger` into your code to "pause" the code at that point.  For example:

```
def hello
    @users = Users.all()
    debugger
end
```

Then, when starting the server, call it with:

```
rails server --debugger
```

Answer (score 1):

Pry (and pry-remote) might be what you're looking for.  I have no experience with it, but this is what it's supposed to let you do.

https://github.com/mon-ouie/pry-remote